# Calculate $\lim_{n\to \infty} \sum_{k=4 n}^{6 n} \frac{n}{k^2+n^2}$

Tags: calculus, limits

Calculate $$\lim_{n\to \infty} \sum_{k=4 n}^{6 n} \frac{n}{k^2+n^2}$$

There are only three terms to look at. I try the first one, $k=4n$ and I simplify it to $$\frac{1}{(4^2+1)n}$$
and that goes to zero when $x \to \infty$. Same for the other three. But zero is not correct.

Comment: There are $2n+1$ terms, not 3.

Answer (score 1):

$$\frac{n}{k^2+n^2}=\frac{1}{n}\times \frac{1}{(k/n)^2+1}$$

Now use integration. [Hint: $\frac{1}{n}=dx$]

Answer (score 0):

$$\lim_{n\to \infty} \sum_{k=4 n}^{6 n} \frac{n}{k^2+n^2}$$

$$=\lim_{n\to \infty} \sum_{k=1}^{6 n} \frac{n}{k^2+n^2}-\lim_{n\to \infty} \sum_{k=1}^{4n} \frac{n}{k^2+n^2}+\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{4n}{n^2+n^2}$$

Now, $$\lim_{n\to \infty} \sum_{k=1}^{6 n} \frac{n}{k^2+n^2}=\lim_{m\to\infty}\sum_{k=1}^m\frac{\frac m6}{k^2+\left(\frac m6\right)^2}=\frac16\lim_{m\to\infty}\frac1m\sum_{k=1}^m\frac1{36\left(\frac km\right)^2+1}$$

Now use $$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac1n\sum_{r=1}^n f\left(\frac rn\right)=\int_0^1f(x)dx$$